# Rendering when mapping over normalized redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using the normalized state pattern, and need to render all objects in a part of the state tree, so I am attempting to map over them and render. But the indices keep rendering along with the object. Why is this happening?:

my state is shaped by the action:

```
export function createNew(personId) {
 const personEntry = fromJS({
  [personId] : {
  id: personId, 
  somestring: "foo",
   }
 });
 return {
  type: NEW_THING,
  personEntry,
 };
}
```

and reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
 peopleList: {},
});

 ...
case NEW_THING:   
        return state
            .update('peopleList', map => map.merge(action.personEntry));
```

and a component to render if passed a peopleList

```
function PeopleThumbnails(props) {
 const list = props.list;
 const listItems = list.map(item =>
    <li>{item.get('somestring')}</li>
    );
 return (
    <ul>
        {listItems}
    </ul>
 )
};
export default PeopleThumbnails;
```

and then use it in `index.js`:

```
<PeopleThumbnails list={collection}>
 ...
 ...
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
 collection: myReselectSelector()
})
```

now user causes the actions `createNew('one')`, `createNew('two')`, and everything works correctly, except the rogue rendering of the index/personId.

```
<ul>
   "one"
   <li>foo</li>
   "two"
   <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `listItems` is still an immutable map. The map function returns a new map when applied to a map. If you only need to render `somestring` as a list you need to convert a map to an array by something like `[...map.values()]`.

Comment: ah yes!  i can also just use `{listItems.valueSeq()}`. thank you

Comment: What does `myReselectSelector` look like?